# Issue tracking software that support multiple repositories

Tags: svn, project-management, version-control, issue-tracking

We are just starting to be using subversion as our SCM software at my job, I would need some advise here.

My project manager would like to use only one instance of a software to manage every projects we have (so we don't want to install a trac instance for each project we start it's kind of an overload).I heard trac can support multiple repositories but it is experimental only and we are looking for something stable.

If subversion is not the way to go (IE: no software available) we might consider to switch to something else (CVS/VSS/Git/etc..) that would have a software that supports this function.

Comment: How is redmine?
www.redmine.org

Comment: Tryed. It's been 3 hours now and still won't install under IIS7. Don't think it's the most suitable idea. :/

Answer (score 2):

With regard to VCS support from issue tracking software, Subversion is definitely one of your best choices (if not THE best choice, today). Not only is it a solid and popular VCS, but I haven't seen a major issue tracking system that *doesn't* support Subversion.

I've used a single instance of [Jira](http://www.atlassian.com/software/jira/) with multiple projects in Subversion with no trouble. I haven't used Trac so I can't comment on that.

Comment: Interesting one but does not not integrate Fisheye on the starter edition. Which is quite necessary.

Comment: Fisheye is not actually necessary. I haven't used Jira with Fisheye but Jira works perfectly well when hooked up to ViewVC or any other source control browser. With one click you can immediately see the source control diff associated with a particular issue. Use Fisheye only if you believe it is significantly better than the free alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend [SourceGear's Fortress](http://www.sourcegear.com/fortress/). It's free for a single user.

Answer (score 0):

I've used and heartily recommend [redmine](http://www.redmine.org/) in this sort of situation. Seamless integration with svn and other source control systems. Multi-project, multi-user, loads of plugs, very flexible ... and I think it looks pretty good too.

I don't use it at the moment and do miss it.

http://www.redmine.org/

Comment: Sounds really neat yep but not installable under IIS7 or with loads of difficulties.